# Figure of data overlayed and corresponding plot of graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have [11 binary datasets](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njsuvdajt1vx30/data1.mat?dl=0) all size 297x258 saved in `data1`  and I would like to produce an image with these data overlapped, each assigned a different color with the background removed (white). An example of the desired output is shown in this image:

[image: Overlap]

I generate the figures of these datasets using:

```
figure, imshow(data1{1}),axis image, colormap(jet)
```

Additionally, any help finding the average increase in size (increase in y-axis) between `data1{1}` and `data1{11}` for every x value increment is also appreciated. Each set of data `data1{1}`, `data1{2}`, ...`data1{11}` is representative of times 0, 1, ...11 respectively and I would like to plot a graph of the average increase in y-axis against the x-axis (1:297). Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

My thoughts so far are:

```
for x=1:x_dim % where xdim is 297 (along the X-axis)
    for y=1:ydim % where ydim is 258 (along the y-axis)
        % execute code to determine increase in y-direction between
        % binary datasets data1{1}, data1{2},...data1{11}. 
        % Then compute average for growth in the y-direction between each time
    end
    % Plot figure of average increase in y-axis against x-axis.
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the code for the figures you wanted:

```
all_data = cell2mat(flipud(data1.'));
all_data = diag(repelem(linspace(1,70,11),size(data1{1},1)))*logical(all_data);

% option 1:
figure('Position',[450 100 200 900],'Color',[1 1 1]);
C = colormap('jet');
C = [1 1 1;C];
colormap(C)
imagesc(all_data)
axis image
axis off

% option 2:
all_data(1:size(data1{1},1):size(all_data,1),:) = nan(11,size(all_data,2));
stack = nan(size(all_data));
toprow = zeros(1,size(all_data,2));
for k = 1:size(all_data,2)
    tmp = nonzeros(flipud(all_data(:,k)));
    stack(1:numel(tmp),k) = tmp;
    toprow(k) = numel(tmp);
end
figure('Position',[650 100 200 900],'Color',[1 1 1]);
C = colormap('jet');
C = [1 1 1;C];
colormap(C)
image(stack(1:max(toprow.'),:))
axis xy
axis off
```

Which gives this:

[image: stack_figures]

option 1 no the left, and option 2 on the right.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would it be possible to capture the transition between data1{1}, data1{2}, ... data1{11} with the boundaries included. With the lines it is difficult to observe where the objects end as 'islands' that are ahead of the data can not be distinguished.

Comment: Number 3 is what I have in mind of producing. Thank you.

Comment: Would also be interested to know how you also produced number 5. Thanks.

Comment: @a.kk see my edit with the code for the selected options.